# Is there a free personal license for Valve Source Engine like the Unreal Development Kit

Tags: game-engine

I was wondering if there is a free student/personal license for downloading Valve source engine for learning purposes. I mean like the freeware Unreal Development Kit which is based on Unreal Engine.

Answer (score 2):

If you own a game on steam that comes with the Source SDK then you can freely download it on that account via the Tools tab in the library.

It allows you to create maps for games you own, or create entirely new mods based off of those games.

If you don't own a compatible game on steam, you should probably buy the pack that comes with Garry's mod and Counter Strike: Source.

Answer (score 0):

The development kit is free to anybody that wants to download it. Just install Steam, and go to Tools, and you can download the development kit.

If you are asking about the actual source code of the engine, I don't think Valve releases that to anybody.

Answer (score 0):

Source Sdk isn't source engine itself.
source sdk is tool for maps, viewing models that would soon be added to game.
Source engine is were maps and models are being ported, also adding A.I to bots are made in engine itself